# Find an ID field from a list based on selected spinner item - sqlite

Tags: android, list, sqlite, android-spinner

I have a spinner that's being populated from a list that's queried from an SQLite DB. The query returns an id(hivetypelistid) and a name(hivetypelist) field. The name is displayed in the spinner, but I want to write the corresponding ID back to the DB. How do I get the ID field from the selected spinner option - name please?

Spinner query and adapter:

```
spinnerHiveType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerHiveType);
List<AMClasses.HiveType> hivetypes = mDataSource.getHivetypes();
ArrayAdapter<AMClasses.HiveType> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, hivetypes);
spinnerHiveType.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hivetype class:

public HiveType(String hivetypelistid, String hivetypelist)

Comment: As usual get selected item then get hivetypelistid from this item... Guess, how many times question how get selected item was asked here on SO already? Second possibility is to use `id` passed to callback but then you have make adapter use stables id.

Comment: from inside the onSelectedItem listener: selectedHiveTypeID = adapter.getItem(position).getHivetypelistid().toString();

Comment: thanks for your help :)